# Mvc pattern: where should I place this php code?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm developing a php application and enforcing a strict mvc pattern  whenever possible. I have a view,the header of the page, which should change the background image depending on the current month. Where should I place the php logic to decide which image to use as the Background? Inside the view file or on the caller (The parent file which includes the view)? If I put the code in the caller then I have to replicate the logic for each page (Every page has the same header view). I could put the logic inside the view, avoiding code duplication,  but should a view supposed to have only view code? (no business logic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep in mind that view is not a template for the application. View is that piece of code that has the responsibility for the UI. So the logic for the background definitely belongs to the view. Also at classical MVC you have 1view 1controller ratio (UserView-UserController etc)

Comment: ok thanks. But then the view would know about the list of available images to display (basically an array of .png filenames). I don't like too much scattering those info all over the places. What do you suggest? Is it ok to have such information inside a view?

Comment: itself this array is not a problem for the view. But if i was at your situation i would try to answer some questions like... how does this view collects this information? how the view manipulate this array? etc etc. The only thing that view does is to take information and put it int the correct "place" like "take this and put it over here, take that and put it over there..."